How to i keep css code such that on print bodyContent need to be printed below 310 pixel
My goal is to print static table .pageHeader on all pages and .bodyContent 310px below (after .pageHeader).
Below CSS was working previously but after Chrome and Firefox update it is not working properly. The first page is working properly but not the second page and onwards; .bodyContent overlaps .pageHeader.
In the HTML I have two tables, one with class pageHeader and one with class bodyContent.
@media print {
  .bodyContent {
    padding-top: 310px;
  }
  
  table.pageHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  } 
}


Please show the relevant HTML structure.

while in print mode, try to keep all elements as position static. I tried ctrl+p with this site (stackoverflow.com). Here the header is removed from the print and it looks elegant. You can also remove the header if that cause some overlapping issue.

@AHaworth it is simple. two tables inside a div. First table with class name pageHeader and second table with class name bodyContent. pageHeader table consist of logo and company address and details (one row and two column). bodyContent will have dynamic content with 3 column

@SudiptoRoy requirement is such that need header in all pages

It may be simple but I'd still need to see it as my interpretation of your verbal description may be wrong.
